# How to control block XML cache via admin?

Tags: magento2, blocks, xml, cache

I've created a condition in my admin panel to enable or disable a feature in my module. In my XML I used the `ifconfig` to check if it's enabled or disabled. I want to disable the cache in the entire page if my module is enabled.

will `ifconfig` skip the `cache` parameter if disabled?

```
<block ifconfig="mycompany_mymodule/general/enable" cacheable="false" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="mymodule" as="mymodule" template="Mycompany_Mymodule::redirect.phtml" before="-">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Mycompany\Mymodule\ViewModel\Helper</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Thank you!

Comment: If so this could be really useful. I'm wondering if you could give it a try and check request headers before and after to see if it makes a difference.